# Failing to recognize specific .pdf file as pdf and opens it in plain-text

Tags: apache, pdf, mime-types

I upgraded Apache from 2.2 to 2.4.

The problem is when I try to open pm.pdf file, it displays plain text.
Any other pdf in any folder including the folder pm.pdf is in opens normally.
It is just this one pdf file that is giving me trouble and only in IE.

httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
</IfModule>

# Adobe Portable Document Format (PDF) compound image
    AddType application/pdf .pdf
    AddType application/x-pdf .pdf
    AddType application/x-bzpdf .pdf
    AddType application/x-gzpdf .pdf
```

mime.types:

```
application/pdf  pdf
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do the HTTP headers from the server say when "it displays plain text"? The problem could be your browser.

Comment: @bzlm The only thing I can find on server is "GET /pm/pm.pdf HTTP/1.1" 206 65536. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Technically, it wasn't so much a question as a way to get you looking in the right place. When a browser displays content as plain text instead of sending it to the correct application or downloading it or showing it as the correct type, either the server is presenting said content erroneously or the browser is misbehaving. To rule out the former, inspect the HTTP headers actually sent to the browser, perhaps using a HTTP proxy like Fiddler. The server log entry you provided provides no insight into the matter; it just says your browser requested the file.

Comment: @bzlm I don't know how to get passed self-signed certificate. This just adds more work for me :(

Comment: Are you using Fiddler? If you configure it to decrypt and inspect HTTPS, then it won't matter whether the certificate is self-signed. More work, and more insight!